# Spark Scala java.sql.date vs. org.apache.spark.sql.types.DateType

Tags: scala, datetime, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert a String to a DateType in a Spark dataframe.

The date Strings are formatted in datetime like "yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"

I am doing the "creationdate" conversion like:

```
   val df2 = df.withColumn("creationdate2", $"creationdate".cast(DateType))
             .drop($"creationdate")
             .withColumnRenamed("creationdate2", "creationdate")
```

On the surface this appears to work, the strings lose their hour/minute/second data and appear as "date" upon a printSchema().  The when I extract a vaue from the dataframe and get the type, I see it is of java.sql.date and not the spark sql DateType.  It all seems fine but when I pipe the data to its destination, Elastic Search, it complains that the date data cannot be parsed.  This leads me to believe my string to DateType conversion is incorrect. Help?

I am feeding it to Elastic Search using the [type conversion table here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html) as reference.

Comment: Don't really know how to solve the problem. But if you format the date time back as string YYYY-MM-DD, elastic search might be able to figure out it's a date.

Comment: @Psidom That worked, thanks!  I got hung up on the documentation's type mapping and overlooked that it could auto convert. Wow.